# cypress: give custome messgage and property name

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, cypress, chai

In cypress I am asserting an element as below:

```js
cy.get('[data-test="description"]').should('be.visible');
```

and this displays as
[image]

This is what I am looking for:

1. I can pass a custom property name so that cypress displays the message as:
   `expected MyElement to be visible`
2. I can pass a custom message both for success/failure of assertion. Something like it can display:

   - success: MyElement is present on the screen.
   - error: MyElement is not present on the screen.

Chaijs Expect has this functionality as:
Every expect method accepts an optional parameter message:

```js
expect(1).to.be.above(2, 'nooo why fail??');
expect(1, 'nooo why fail??').to.be.above(2);
```